# How to wait for JavaScript to render before requesting with Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to request the HTML of a website generated with JavaScript so I can scrape the information with BeautifulSoup. The problem is when I try requesting the HTML, the information I receive is before the page is rendered. The following is the code I am running:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://www.edwarddan.com/projects'

this_session = HTMLSession()
response = this_session.get(url)
response.html.render()

print(response.text)
print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
names = soup.findAll("div")
```

As a result, I get the following HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
  <script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/cTVctQJ-rr0oH623j2V4Pf03v-o.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Edward Dan -- Last updated 1/21/2021" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
  <title>Edward Dan</title>
  <link href="/static/css/main.d231a676.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script>
    ! function(e) {
      function r(r) {
        for (var n, p, l = r[0], a = r[1], f = r[2], c = 0, s = []; c < l.length; c++) p = l[c], Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, p) && o[p] && s.push(o[p][0]), o[p] = 0;
        for (n in a) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, n) && (e[n] = a[n]);
        for (i && i(r); s.length;) s.shift()();
        return u.push.apply(u, f || []), t()
      }

      function t() {
        for (var e, r = 0; r < u.length; r++) {
          for (var t = u[r], n = !0, l = 1; l < t.length; l++) {
            var a = t[l];
            0 !== o[a] && (n = !1)
          }
          n && (u.splice(r--, 1), e = p(p.s = t[0]))
        }
        return e
      }
      var n = {},
        o = {
          1: 0
        },
        u = [];

      function p(r) {
        if (n[r]) return n[r].exports;
        var t = n[r] = {
          i: r,
          l: !1,
          exports: {}
        };
        return e[r].call(t.exports, t, t.exports, p), t.l = !0, t.exports
      }
      p.m = e, p.c = n, p.d = function(e, r, t) {
        p.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, {
          enumerable: !0,
          get: t
        })
      }, p.r = function(e) {
        "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
          value: "Module"
        }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
          value: !0
        })
      }, p.t = function(e, r) {
        if (1 & r && (e = p(e)), 8 & r) return e;
        if (4 & r && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
        var t = Object.create(null);
        if (p.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", {
            enumerable: !0,
            value: e
          }), 2 & r && "string" != typeof e)
          for (var n in e) p.d(t, n, function(r) {
            return e[r]
          }.bind(null, n));
        return t
      }, p.n = function(e) {
        var r = e && e.__esModule ? function() {
          return e.default
        } : function() {
          return e
        };
        return p.d(r, "a", r), r
      }, p.o = function(e, r) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r)
      }, p.p = "/";
      var l = this["webpackJsonpmy-app"] = this["webpackJsonpmy-app"] || [],
        a = l.push.bind(l);
      l.push = r, l = l.slice();
      for (var f = 0; f < l.length; f++) r(l[f]);
      var i = a;
      t()
    }([])
  </script>
  <script src="/static/js/2.c42d857a.chunk.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/main.60cdc4af.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**This HTML produces none of the elements that are the seen when the website has finished generating.** I was wondering if there was a way I can **wait for the website to finish running JavaScript** and create all its elements before fetching said information?

I am using **HTMLSession** because, from research, I found that it allow websites to load. Specifically, the line `response.html.render()` should render the page before fetching data, however, it doesn't seem to be working as **nothing has rendered.**

I have also tried using Selenium in combination with PhantomJS, however, it seems that Selenium is a bit outdated and I would prefer not to use that?

Does anyone know how if there is a way to wait for the JS to finish running with **HTMLSession**? If not, is there another library I can use that will allow me to have this functionality?

Comment: If you are not satisfied with selenium, then there are other libraries, for example: marionette (firefox), pyppeteer (chrome). You can also manually model and send requests until the page is completely loaded, but this sucks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong attribute `response.text`, [official website suggests](https://github.com/psf/requests-html#javascript-support) to use `response.html` after rendering.

Replacement for your code:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.edwarddan.com/projects'

this_session = HTMLSession()
response = this_session.get(url)
response.html.render()

print(response.html.raw_html)
print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.raw_html, "html.parser")
names = soup.findAll("div")
```

We have to use HTML to parse in `BeautifulSoup` so, we are using `response.html.raw_html` to get raw HTML.

---

And it is better to use `response.html.find()` function to search rather then using `BeautifulSoup` because it will be faster, then parsing by BeautifulSoup and searching elements.

Example for your code:

```py
this_session = HTMLSession()
response = this_session.get(url)
response.html.render()

print(response.html.find('div'))
print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
```